# Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal while using vi and grep

Tags: grep, vi

I am running the following command to view error log

```
vi mysite_com_error.log-2019060 | grep 'Jun 08:23'
```

but I am getting the following error:

> Vim: Warning: Output is not to a terminal

Comment: `vi` is an interactive editor?  shouldn't you be using `cat` or some other command?

Comment: @guiverc: or just `grep` the file without `cat`? `grep 'Jun 08:23' mysite_com_error.log-2019060`